# How to convert object of Array into seprate array using gson?

Tags: java, android, gson

I am getting API response like this

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Chapters": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Chapter": 11,
      "ChapterName": "Nuclear Theory ",
    }],
 "Subjects": [
    {
      "$id": "117",
      "SubjectId": 9,
      "SubjectName": "Science"
    }],

"Standards": [
    {
      "$id": "151",
      "StandardMasterId": 17,
      "StandardName": "11TH APPEARING (NEET COMBINED)",
    }]

}
```

I want to convert this response (string) into seprate like `ArrayList<Chapters>, ArrayList<Subjects>`. I have made individual classes for Chapters, Subjects, Standard. 
How can i do this using GSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Gson().fromJson` to convert your response to model object

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(your_response, ApiResponse.class);
```

---

**ApiResponse.java:**

```
public class ApiResponse {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("Chapters")
    public List<Chapter> chapters = null;
    @SerializedName("Subjects")
    public List<Subject> subjects = null;
    @SerializedName("Standards")
    public List<Standard> standards = null;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**Standard.java:**

```
public class Standard {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("StandardMasterId")
    public int standardMasterId;
    @SerializedName("StandardName")
    public String standardName;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**Subject.java:**

```
public class Subject {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("SubjectId")
    public int subjectId;
    @SerializedName("SubjectName")
    public String subjectName;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**Chapter.java:**

```
public class Chapter {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("Chapter")
    public int chapter;
    @SerializedName("ChapterName")
    public String chapterName;

    //getter-setter
}
```

---

Moreover your `json` is not valid. Valid `json` should be like this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Chapters": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Chapter": 11,
      "ChapterName": "Nuclear Theory "
    }
  ],
  "Subjects": [
    {
      "$id": "117",
      "SubjectId": 9,
      "SubjectName": "Science"
    }
  ],
  "Standards": [
    {
      "$id": "151",
      "StandardMasterId": 17,
      "StandardName": "11TH APPEARING (NEET COMBINED)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create Model class to parse the data**

```
public class ResponseDataModel {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    private string id;

    @SerializedName("Chapters")
    private List<Chapters> Chapters;


    @SerializedName("Subjects")
    private List<Chapters> Chapters;

    @SerializedName("Standards")
    private List<Chapters> Chapters;



    /** Generate Getter setter methods **/

}
```

**In your main activity try this**

```
String response = "{
  "$id": "1",
  "Chapters": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Chapter": 11,
      "ChapterName": "Nuclear Theory ",
    }],
 "Subjects": [
    {
      "$id": "117",
      "SubjectId": 9,
      "SubjectName": "Science"
    }],

"Standards": [
    {
      "$id": "151",
      "StandardMasterId": 17,
      "StandardName": "11TH APPEARING (NEET COMBINED)",
    }]

}"

Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseDataModel model = gson.fromGson(response,ResponseDataModel.class);

ArrayList<Subject> subjects = model.get....
```